# AES Encryption and Decryption in TypeScript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, encryption, cryptojs

This is my AES encryption code snippet in C#.

```
public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "abcabcabc";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[]
                { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs =
                    new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return clearText;
        }
```

I'm trying to decrypt this is typescript. But unfortunately I'm finding error in decrypting the encrypted data with the above function. Can someone please help me with this

```
const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([73, 118, 97, 110, 32, 77, 101, 100, 118, 101, 100, 101, 118]);
const secret = "abcabcabc";
const keySize = 256 / 32;
const iterations = 1000;
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secret, salt, { keySize: keySize, iterations: iterations });
const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(key.words.slice(0, 4));

const cipherText = "ciphertext";
const cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherText),
    key: key,
    iv: iv,
    salt: salt
});

const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, key, { iv: iv });
const plainText = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(plainText);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post sample data, i.e. a plaintext and the corresponding ciphertext generated with the C# code, so that a test of the JavaScript code is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue and solved with the below fix.

while decrypting, decode the encrypted text and then process the decrypt algorithm.

Send the encrypted text to decrypt method after decoding. Below is the method to decode the encrypted text

let data = decodeURIComponent(encryptedText); // this data will be the input for your decrypt method.

That's how I resolved my issue. Hope this helps for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).